# Angular Newbie: Debugging Typescript Error "All declarations of 'imageLoader' must have identical type parameters"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've had a rough go trying to figure out some of the Angular 2 basics.  I learned that script tags can only be used in index.html, so I'm trying to translate one of my js files to ts in the component class of app.component.ts.  I'd be truly grateful for any assistance you could give.

Could you help me to understand and resolve the errors with my TS translation?

Here is the original JavaScript:

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Here's my current TypeScript including reported errors:

[image: Image detailing current TypeScript translation progress as well as VS Code reported errors]

app.component.html:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <label>Image File:</label><br/>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Lines 11 - 14 need to be inside a class method. For line 17 remove the word function so TypeScript sees "handleImage" as the name of the method. That should get you started but there's likely other changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be the appropriate angular 2 version:

```
import{ Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: 'pc-app',

templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {
    title: string = 'POSTERIZER';

    handleImage(e:any) {
        let imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
        let canvas: any = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event:any) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                canvas.setAttribute('width', '599');
                canvas.setAttribute('height', '599');
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution.  I was wondering how I might include "imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);".  Is there a way to set this outside of the handleImage method on page load?

Comment: You can use '(change)="handleImage()"' on the imageLoader html element. And make 'handleImage' a function in the component class.

Comment: Id recommend playing with it in a plunker and comment here if you get stuck

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you very much!  Would you have any suggestions or know any articles that might help me to better understand how to compose TypeScript from JavaScript?

Comment: There are many resources online, if you understand javascript really well, the official typescript docs is the best place to start.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I'll do as you suggest